# LINQ Select - CS0411 The type arguments cannot be inferred from the usage - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c#, linq

**Goal:** ForEach extension masking Select.

**Reason:** Select allows for method chaining while foreach does not; ForEach is more readable than Select.

The problem I'm running into is that I'm getting this error.

> The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Select(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Func)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly. (CS0411)

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> elements, Action<T, int> action)
{
    elements.Select((elem, i) => action(elem, i));
}
```

I've tried doing `elements.Select((T elem, int i) => action(elem, i));` but that produces the same error.

I've also attempted using Func instead of Action but there doesn't seem to be any way to use void for the return (which is what Action is for anyways). If I define the method to take a Func instead of Action then when I try to call it using Action I get the same error.

```
public static IEnumerable<TOut> ForEach<TIn, TOut>(this IEnumerable<TIn> elements, 
    Func<TIn, int, TOut> function)
{
    return elements.Select((elem, i) => function(elem, i))
        .ToList();
}
```

I don't understand which arguments cannot be inferred. There are ways I could get around this (using a for loop or foreach loop and track the index), but I would still like to figure out why this won't work.

**Edit:** I also just realized my other ForEach for Action (no index) also gets this error when I switch from a foreach loop to calling Select.

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> elements, Action<T> action)
{
    elements.ToList().Select((T elem) => action(elem));
    /*foreach (var elem in elements)
        action(elem);*/
}
```

Comment: Why use `Select` at all? If you want to write `ForEach`, just use a `foreach` statement...

Comment: `elements.Select<T>((elem, i) => action(elem, i));`?

Comment: @DigiFriend: `action` doesn't return anything `Select` is a projection.

Comment: @JonSkeet to get the index option

Comment: Note that if your first method compiled, it wouldn't actually do anything, due to lazy evaluation.

Comment: @BlakeThingstad: So keep an index yourself... it's very, very simple to do.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, I agree, I addressed this at the end of my question. I could use a for loop but I still don't understand why I'm getting the error. _"There are ways I could get around this (using a for loop or foreach loop and track the index), but..."_

Comment: Well do you not understand *any* of the errors? Do you understand that `Select` is meant to take a projection, to go from one type to another? What do you expect the compiler to infer here, given that `action(elem)` and `action(elem, i)` don't return anything?

Comment: If you're only interested in figuring out why it doesn't work, *that* should be the stated goal - because the best answer for the goal at the top of the question is "use a foreach loop" (inside your ForEach implementation).

Comment: Btw, the middle version using a `Func` compiles fine for me, just as I'd expect it to.

Comment: @JonSkeet No I guess I don't understand projection (the first time I've heard that term in this context). The middle one compiles fine, but then I can't get any way to still use an Action instead of Func when using the extension method.

Comment: @BlakeThingstad : look at Scott's answer. He explained everything and give you the proper solution

Comment: @fharreau ah yes, his updated answer does seem to address some of the questions I had for Jon Skeet. Thank you

Comment: @BlakeThingstad What would a IEnumerable<void> look like?

Comment: @MarkPeters I think at least part of my confusion is from being misled from my noob past in LINQ. I just about commented `var nums = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }; nums.Select(Console.WriteLine);` until I got the same error! I guess it just doesn't work the way I had thought it does.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that `Select` expects a return value (you're projecting an object into something else) - of which your `Action` is returning `void`.  `void` can't be converted into `T`, which is what Select is expecting.

The simple fix is to ensure something is returned at the end of your select function:

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> elements, Action<T, int> action)
{
    elements.Select((elem, i) =>
    {
        action(elem, i);
        return elem;
    }).Count();
}
```

The action is called, and the collection continues to be enumerated.  We need to call `Count` because nothing will actually happen until we attempt to get a value from each enumeration (thank you Jon Skeet!)

*Note that this isn't how Select should be used - the OP specifically asked why/how to make it work with it.*

To do this properly, as mentioned in the comments, the solution is to use an actual `foreach` loop with a counter:

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> elements, Action<T, int> action)
{
    int count = 0;
    foreach (var item in elements)
    {
        action(item, count++);
    }
}
```

If you want to allow method chaining, you can do it this way:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> elements, Action<T, int> action) 
{ 
    int count = 0; 
    foreach (var item in elements) 
    {
        action(item, count++); 
        yield return item; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Except that won't actually do anything when you call it. Giving an answer with a method which *looks* like it might be useful, but isn't, isn't actually a useful answer IMO.

Comment: @JonSkeet Ahh!  Good point, "fixed" it...  I'll add a note explaining why we need ToList.

Comment: That's then creating garbage pointlessly. `Count()` would be more efficient, but fundamentally this whole thing is a bad idea.

Comment: @JonSkeet I never thought of that, thanks for showing me that trick.  I've added an example of the correct solution.  Sorry to disappoint  :(

Comment: @Scott Regarding to the OP (`Select allows for method chaining while foreach does not;`), I guess he would appreciate something like : 
`public static IEnumerable<T> ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> elements, Action<T, int> action)
        {
            int count = 0;
            foreach (var item in elements)
            {
                action(item, count++);
                yield return item;
            }
        }`

Comment: @fharreau Community wiki'd my answer, please feel free to add any more solutions or post your own answer - this question has some controversy surrounding it!

Comment: @Scott Yes it does! I was hesitant to post my question because I thought it might stir up some of that controversy.